# Checkbox form symfony

Tags: angularjs, database, forms, symfony, twig

I have a backend form which one is connected with a table. It's a configuration field and inside we can find something like a json.

[image: Database field sample]

The form already exist (**the limitHours field is working fine** and you can see check how is it declared below).

So, i just added this new flag enable_rotation_system.

In my form:

```
->add('limitHours', 'number', array('required' => false, 'mapped'=>false , 'label' => 'Heure limite positionnement'))
->add('enable_rotation_system', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'mapped' => false , 'label' => 'Activer les rotations'))
```

In the view:

```
    <span class="input text fullWidth">
        {{ form_label(form.posConfiguration.limitHours) }}{{ form_errors(form.posConfiguration.limitHours) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.posConfiguration.limitHours, {'attr': {'value': posConfigurations['configuration']['limitHours'] }} ) }}
    </span>
    <span class="checkboxInput">
        {{ form_widget(form.posConfiguration.enable_rotation_system , {'attr': {'value': posConfigurations['configuration']['enable_rotation_system'] }} ) }}
        {{ form_label(form.posConfiguration.enable_rotation_system) }}{{ form_errors(form.posConfiguration.enable_rotation_system) }}
    </span>
```

What happens: when i send my form with my checkbox tick, then in the database field i get: **"enable_rotation_system":""**
But, true or may be 1 was expected here....

Now, if i send my form with my checkbox not tick, then in the database field the enable_rotation_system flag doesn't exist anymore. Only "limitHours":"18" remains.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm not sure how the data are sent, but i think angular is used.

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'ng-app': 'moduleApp', 'ng-controller': 'MainCtrl as ctrl', 'novalidate': 'novalidate' } }) }}
```

At the bottom i got this

```
angular.module('moduleApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var self = this;

    self.posConfig = {{ posConfigurations|json_encode|raw }};
    self.moduleConfig = {{ configuration|raw }};

    self.submitForm = function(event, form) {
        if (form.$valid) {
            $("#cpn_corebundle_moduleinstance_configuration").val(JSON.stringify(self.moduleConfig));
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: maybe you could show how you save your datas ...

Comment: I added more details in the first post, but i'm not really sure how it's done. This part was developped by someone else before i took back the project...and at this time it wasn't even on git so i can't find clues...